# How to adapt acoustic model for UK/Indian accent

Tags: ios, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, cmusphinx, corpus

I am working on speech recognition for Indian Accent. For better recognition, I want to create language model for Indian accent.

The tutorial I got describes about Linux OS. Is there any way to do in Windows for acoustic model adaptation ?? Is there any alternative other than recorded sound to create a acoustic model ??

I found online language model tool here >>http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/tools/lmtool.html
But it is US accent.

Is there any online tool to create Indian/UK accent language model ??

Comment: Please comment the reason for down vote

Comment: Asking for tool recommendations is off- topic. And what does this have to do with iOS?

Comment: @jrturton I am developing an app in iOS7. And I am using openears tools for speech recognition. I have optimized to get the best result using openears. But Accent problems can't be solved using it. And I have been redirected to acoustic model adapting. In Acoustic Model adapting, as a newbei in speech recognition, I found a lot of problems which I have shared

Comment: Well you might want to mention that in the question, instead of Linux and windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First a quick clarification. Creating a new language model will not help you with accents. The language model only specifies in which orders the words can appear. You are looking for acoustic, not language, model adaptation.

Because adaptation is a complex process, there are not good online tools for it (the one you linked is a language model tool). I would recommend downloading SphinxTrain at http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net for a good all-purpose adaptation/training tool. There are many tutorials and forums to help you get started.